# Change base weight of basket to update the shipping costs in WooCommerce

Tags: woocommerce

I would like to add base of 170g to basket in Woocommerce as weight of base package (used to send items). So, all products/items weigth would be added to 170g and make total weigth of order.

I have found something like: Change weight of each cart item to update the shipping costs in WooCommerce on Stack Overflow. This exactly what I need, but not for each item, but once in every order.

Sorry my for English :)

Comment: I am sorry that was my first time here. I will do my best next time.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using `WC_Cart->get_cart_contents_weight()` method, you can use the `woocommerce_cart_contents_weight` filter to alter the total weight.

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_cart_contents_weight', 'prefix_filter_cart_contents_weight' );
function prefix_filter_cart_contents_weight( $weight ) {
    /**
     * Adding 170 units to the total cart weight.
     */
    return $weight + 170;
}
```

https://gist.github.com/vanbo/f71ecf4597b79baecd0a71250011149d

Comment: This is not a question. What do you want to do? What is your goal?

Comment: I am posting an answer to Artur's question not asking myself

Comment: Ooops! My bad, first time in the review section ;)

Comment: Frizlab, you are champion :) It works! :) Thank you very much for your help :) Have a beautiful weekend ;)